# Getting a super weird error during gradle build of my flutter app

Tags: flutter, gradle

When I tried to run my flutter app, this is the error which I encountered. I tried checking out to the last commit(the app worked flawlessly the last time I committed) but that didn't help. I tried to clean cache using flutter clean and reinstalled all packages with flutter pub get. Didn't work. Tried cleaning the build folder using gradlew clean and tried running gradlew build. But it still gave the same error. How am I supposed to debug this?

```
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1072:60: Error: Can't find '}' to match '{'.
      if (_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.defunct) {
                                                           ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1071:15: Error: Can't find '}' to match '{'.
    assert(() {
              ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1096:7: Error: Expected a class member, but got 'if'.
      if (_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created && !mounted) {
      ^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1096:10: Error: Expected an identifier, but got '('.
Try inserting an identifier before '('.
      if (_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created && !mounted) {
         ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1096:32: Error: Expected ')' before this.
      if (_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created && !mounted) {
                               ^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1107:7: Error: Expected a class member, but got 'return'.
      return true;
      ^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1107:14: Error: Expected a class member, but got 'true'.
      return true;
             ^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1107:18: Error: Expected a class member, but got ';'.
      return true;
                 ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1108:6: Error: Expected a declaration, but got '('.
    }());
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1108:7: Error: Expected a declaration, but got ')'.
    }());
      ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1108:8: Error: Expected a declaration, but got ')'.
    }());
       ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1108:9: Error: Unexpected token ';'.
    }());
        ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1110:5: Error: 'assert' can't be used as an identifier because it's a keyword.
Try renaming this to be an identifier that isn't a keyword.
    assert(() {
    ^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1110:12: Error: Expected an identifier, but got '('.
Try inserting an identifier before '('.
    assert(() {
           ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1110:15: Error: Expected ')' before this.
    assert(() {
              ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1128:9: Error: Expected a function body or '=>'.
Try adding {}.
    }());
        ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1129:13: Error: Unexpected token '!'.
    _element!.markNeedsBuild();
            ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1129:5: Error: A function declaration needs an explicit list of parameters.
Try adding a parameter list to the function declaration.
    _element!.markNeedsBuild();
    ^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1129:14: Error: Expected '{' before this.
    _element!.markNeedsBuild();
             ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1129:14: Error: Expected a declaration, but got '.'.
    _element!.markNeedsBuild();
             ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1129:31: Error: Expected a function body or '=>'.
Try adding {}.
    _element!.markNeedsBuild();
                              ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1130:3: Error: Expected a declaration, but got '}'.
  }
  ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1329:37: Error: Expected a function body or '=>'.
Try adding {}.
  Widget build(BuildContext context);
                                    ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1359:1: Error: Expected a declaration, but got '}'.
}
^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar.dart:787:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'didChangeDependencies'.
    super.didChangeDependencies();
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar.dart:801:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'dispose'.
    super.dispose();
          ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/banner.dart:243:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'dispose'.
    super.dispose();
          ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_app_bar.dart:125:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'didChangeDependencies'.
    super.didChangeDependencies();
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/calendar_date_picker.dart:184:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'didChangeDependencies'.
    super.didChangeDependencies();
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/calendar_date_picker.dart:522:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'didChangeDependencies'.
    super.didChangeDependencies();
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/calendar_date_picker.dart:542:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'dispose'.
    super.dispose();
          ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/calendar_date_picker.dart:889:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'didChangeDependencies'.
    super.didChangeDependencies();
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/calendar_date_picker.dart:902:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'dispose'.
    super.dispose();
          ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/date_picker.dart:1680:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'dispose'.
    super.dispose();
          ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/date_picker.dart:1843:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'dispose'.
    super.dispose();
          ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/date_picker.dart:2224:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'didChangeDependencies'.
    super.didChangeDependencies();
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/date_picker.dart:2237:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'dispose'.
    super.dispose();
          ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/date_picker.dart:2804:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'dispose'.
    super.dispose();
          ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/date_picker.dart:2809:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'didChangeDependencies'.
    super.didChangeDependencies();
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/desktop_text_selection.dart:143:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'dispose'.
    super.dispose();
          ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/drawer.dart:370:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'didChangeDependencies'.
    super.didChangeDependencies();
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart:1209:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'dispose'.
    super.dispose();
          ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expansion_tile.dart:419:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'didChangeDependencies'.
    super.didChangeDependencies();
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_decoration.dart:277:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'deactivate'.
    super.deactivate();
          ^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_well.dart:805:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'dispose'.
    super.dispose();
          ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_date_picker_form_field.dart:156:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'dispose'.
    super.dispose();
          ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_date_picker_form_field.dart:161:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'didChangeDependencies'.
    super.didChangeDependencies();
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart:1856:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'didChangeDependencies'.
    super.didChangeDependencies();
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! It happened cause I had accidentally deleted a line from flutter's source code while analyzing an error.